# Get only numbers in output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to get only numbers from this:
`release/M_0.1.0`
thus, need to extract with bash to have in output this: 
`0.1.0`.
I have tried this but cannot finish it: 
`echo "release/M_0.1.0" | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'`

And what about if given such string? `relea234se/sdf23_4Mm0.1.0.8`. How to get only `0.1.0.8`? Please pay attention that this can be random digits such as `0.2` or `1.9.1`.

Comment: Is your input coming from a file, a pipe, and variable or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Please check if this `grep` command works

```sh
echo "release/M_0.1.0" | egrep -o '[0-9.]+'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use general parameter expansion parsing to literally remove characters up through the last that isn't digits or dots.

```
$: ver() { echo "${1//*[^.0-9]/}"; }
$: ver release/M_0.1.0
0.1.0
$: ver relea234se/sdf23_4Mm0.1.0.8
0.1.0.8
```

Comment: Darn it, that's the first thing I tried and I got the syntax wrong and thought bash couldn't do it that way :-) !

Comment: I managed something Ed goofed? I think I'll mark this on my calendar and preen for a bit, lol ;)

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you can do:

```
echo "release/M_0.1.0" | sed 's@.*_@@'
```

**Output**:

```
0.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your Input_file will be same as shown samples.

```
echo "$var" | awk -F'_' '{print $2}'
```

OR could use `sub`:

```
echo "$var" | awk '{sub(/.*_/,"")} 1'
```

---

***With simple bash you could use:***

```
echo "${var#*_}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo release/M_0.1.0 | awk -F\_ '{print $2}'
0.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick:

```
$ var='relea234se/sdf23_4Mm0.1.0.8'

$ [[ $var =~ .*[^0-9.](.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
0.1.0.8

$ echo "$var" | sed 's/.*[^0-9.]//'
0.1.0.8

$ echo "$var" | awk -F'[^0-9.]' '{print $NF}'
0.1.0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

if data in `d` file, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/relea.*/.*([0-9][0-9.]*)$/\1/' d
```